# How to not break line on before "?"?

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I am French. In French there must be a space before and after a question mark "?". However, depending on the size of the screen, sometime the "?" is online on the next line. How to prevent this ugly display?

I cannot put a tag inside the question because they are binded.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="errorbox text-left">
            <p></p>
            <ul>
                <li>Question 1 ? </li>
                <li>Question 2 ? </li>
                <li>Question 3 ? </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,

Stéphane.

Comment: You can use '&nbsp;' for unsecable space `<li>Question&nbsp;1?&nbsp;</li>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `&nbsp;` or try to use css `white-space: nowrap;`

```
<li>Question&nbsp;1&nbsp;? </li>
<li>Question&nbsp;2&nbsp;? </li>
<li>Question&nbsp;3&nbsp;? </li>
```

Comment: Hum, it seems to be the only solution. But as I don't know the question before, it means that I have to modify it with some JS...

Comment: As an FYI, nbsp stands for non-breaking space - to help you remember in future

Comment: thanks. But I am facing trouble in jquery. var elnsb = $(elselect).html().html().replace(/ ?/g, "&nbsp;?")

Answer (score -1):

Try this piece of css.

```
li {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: It will go beyond its container.